# Is there supposed to be a gulp file in the development branch?

Tags: quill

The head of my pulled down development branch is: b81ff687b28d41a897d2f527ffb79ef28c89b7a2

There doesn't appear to be a gulp file

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, QuillJS has never used gulp.  The 0.20 branch has a Gruntfile, but it's been removed by the 1.0 branch.

Instead of grunt or gulp, Quill uses [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) for its build tasks.  You can see them defined in the `"scripts"` section of the package.json file.

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config _develop/webpack.config.js --devtool hidden-source-map",
    "start": "npm run build; foreman start -f _develop/procfile",
    "test": "npm run build; karma start _develop/karma.config.js",
    "test:coverage": "webpack --config _develop/webpack.coverage.js; karma start _develop/karma.config.js --reporters coverage",
    "travis": "karma start _develop/karma.config.js --reporters dots,saucelabs"
}
```

These can be run by the command `npm run [name of script]`, e.g. `npm run build`.  (`npm test` exists as its own command which is essentially an alias for `npm run test`; though it handles errors a bit differently)